# Adding VLC codecs to a media player written in C# windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, media-player, windows-store-apps, video-codecs

I'll try to be direct about it

How to take the codecs from VLC media player source code and integrate them in my media player windows 8 app written in C#

PS: I want to publish this app in the store so any one downloads it won't need to install codecs and stuff

I hope this time my question is simple

Comment: Did you check whether you are allowed to redistribute those codecs? My guess would be they are protected by some license preventing either redistribution in commercial or even any form.

Comment: You have no hope of getting these codecs through the Store validation procedure.  They'll use forbidden winapi functions, like CreateFile().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 distinct problems you may have to solve in order to reuse the code in Windows 8 environment.

1.What is the licensing type of VLC / VideoLan sources?

From this link http://www.videolan.org/legal.html , it is clear that the sources under `VideoLan` project are covered under **GPL**. There are some restrictions/recommendations to use a GPL software as captured here http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html#SEC3 . Assuming that you are able to satisfy all requirements, we come to the next question.

2.Is GPL software compatible with Windows 8 environment?

This is a really important question to solve. I am not aware of Windows 8 licensing terms and conditions, but feel this is definitely a numero uno issue for you.

Apart from the cross-licensing issues, I feel that the **most critical issue** for you would be

3.Who pays the royalties or patent fees or legal fees for the different codecs?

Each codec has it's own unique collection of terms and conditions and licensing models. As an app developer, do you charge any fee and in turn manage to pay all the standardization bodies or do you have a model where the device manufacturer / end-user pay the royalties?

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry guys I didn't think about the legal stuff, I thought because VLC is an opensource project so its codecs is free to use in other players :) this is my first real attempt in development and I thought Windows 8 apps is a fresh market to start with

Comment: So is there are codecs that are free to use by developers, and I mean good codecs (like VLC or KMP, MPC-HC), or am I wasting my time ?

Comment: Most of the codecs have some royalties attached as they are filled with patents from different companies. You can get some open-source codecs, but these aren't something which is widely used. Personally, I feel it would be good for you to clarify the legal constraints and proceed with building your app. I think in general, you can use the codecs available in the system. The issue arises when you try include/integrate a new codec library